# IPv6 address compression

Tags: compression, ipv6

I have been compressing IPv6 addresses but for some reason I can't compress this one:
`2​b​0​6​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​1​f​2​b​:​d​7​7​f​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​8​9​c​e​`

This is what I compressed it too: `2b06::1f2b:d77f::89ce`

But this is not working, and I wonder, why.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way to do it: `2b06::1f2b:d77f:0:0:89ce`
You can't have `::` more than once in one address.

This `2b06::1f2b:d77f::89ce` would be ambiguous, as it could expand to
`2b06:0000:1f2b:d77f:0000:0000:0000:89ce`,
`2​b​0​6​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​1​f​2​b​:​d​7​7​f​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​8​9​c​e`, or
`2​b​0​6​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:0000:​1​f​2​b​:​d​7​7​f​:​0​0​0​0​:​8​9​c​e`.

Answer (score 0):

The Standards Track *[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952)* explains:

> [4.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.2.3). Choice
> in Placement of "::"
>
> When there is an alternative choice in the placement of a "::", the
> longest run of consecutive 16-bit 0 fields MUST be shortened (i.e.,
> the sequence with three consecutive zero fields is shortened in
> 2001:0:0:1:0:0:0:1). ***When the length of the consecutive 16-bit 0
> fields are equal (i.e., 2001:db8:0:0:1:0:0:1), the first sequence of
> zero bits MUST be shortened. For example, 2001:db8::1:0:0:1 is correct
> representation.***

Answer (score -1):

You can have more than :: in one address

the correct answer is 2b06::1f2b:d77f:0:0:89ce